# How to change the class of a button on change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input button that I am styling like this:

```
<span class="btn btn-file btn-default">
    <span class="text"></span>
    <input type="file" id="fileinput" name="uploaded_file" />
</span>
```

And changing it with this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".text").html("Change Avatar");
     $('#fileinput').on('change', function() {
         $(".text").text('Avatar Selected');
     });
 });
```

By default, it shows 'Change Avatar'. And when somebody selected a photo, it changes to 'Avatar Selected'.

I'd also like it to change from `btn-default` to `btn-selected`.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the [`.toggleClass()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to toggle both of the classes.

```
$(this).closest('.btn').toggleClass('btn-default btn-selected');
```

```
$(".text").html("Change Avatar");
$('#fileinput').on('change', function () {
    $(".text").text('Avatar Selected');
    $(this).closest('.btn').toggleClass('btn-default btn-selected');
});
```

---

I'd suggest checking if there is actually a file specified, though, because it's possible that a user could select a file and then unselect it.

```
$('#fileinput').on('change', function () {
    if (this.value) {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ..
    }
});
```

You could also use something like this:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rvacrmhz/)

```
$('#fileinput').on('change', function () {    
    $(".text").text(this.value ? 'Avatar Selected' : 'Change Avatar');
    $(this).closest('.btn').removeClass('btn-selected btn-default')
           .addClass(this.value ? 'btn-selected' : 'btn-default');
});
```

In doing so, the parent button element will only have the class `.btn-selected` if a file is actually selected (even when a file is unselected and then reselected; unlike the first suggestion above).